# Entry Data for Journey - Scope and Values

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Does the Entry Data in a Journey stay the same value throughout the Journey if it changes in Salescloud?
My Marketing Cloud Instance is connected to Salecloud via the Marketing Cloud Connector.   I have a Journey that starts with the Entry of the creation of a new record in a custom object using the Salesforce Data option. We have selected several fields to be used in the Journey as Entry Data.  My question is if the journey lasts 30 days and the value of this field changes in Salescloud during that 30 days, will the value be reflected in the journey or does the value stay the same throughout the entire journey?

Comment: Indeed! Didn't think to flag:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entry Event/Journey Data will stay the same. It is a snapshot of when then contact entered the Journey. 
If you need to reference current data I would recommend referencing the synchronized data extensions via Contact Data